# for loop shiny variable assignment

Tags: r, shiny

I have a chunk of code that gets repeated 20 times, where the same information, plots, etc, are displayed, and number of sets of data that gets displayed is dependent on how many fields of input the user selects in a shiny app. Rather than copy/pasting this code and changing the input name from "Job1" to "Job2" in the second chunk, I want to introduce a for loop.  My question is how to have a variable assignment for a shiny input that is sequential.  I have tried paste0 to accomplish what I am trying to do with no luck.

The sample code shows my attempt at a for loop to do the same thing with 4 iterations.  The part of my attempt to make this work is commented out near the top of the ui.  The way it is now works as intended, but as you can see it is not clean and is very tedious.  Also, what would this look like on the server side (my attempt is also commented out right now)

```
      ui <- fluidPage(
      numericInput("num_selected", label = "Fields to Display", value = 0, min = 0, max = 4, step = 1),


      # for (i in 1:4 ) {
      #     conditionalPanel(
      #       condition = "input.num_selected >= i",
      #       textInput(paste0("Name", i), "Name"),
      #       textInput(paste0("Job", i), "Job")
      # )
      # }



    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.num_selected >= 1",
      textInput("Name1", "Name"),
      textInput("Job1", "Job")
    ),



    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.num_selected >= 2",
      textInput("Name2", "Name"),
      textInput("Job2", "Job")
    ),


    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.num_selected >= 3",
      textInput("Name3", "Name"),
      textInput("Job3", "Job")
    ),


    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.num_selected >= 4",
      textInput("Name4", "Name"),
      textInput("Job4", "Job")
    )
    )

    server<-function(input,output,session)
    {
      # for (i in 1:20 ) {
      # output$paste0("Name", i) <- ...
      # output$paste0("Job", i) <- ...
          # }
    }

    shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `tagList()` and `renderUI()`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num_selected", label = "Fields to Display", value = 0, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1),
  uiOutput("condPanels")
)

server<-function(input,output,session){

  output$condPanels <- renderUI({
    # if selected value = 0 dont create a condPanel,...
    if(!input$num_selected) return(NULL)
    tagList(
      lapply(1:input$num_selected, function(nr){
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = paste0("input.num_selected >= ", nr),
          textInput(paste0("Name", nr), "Name"),
          textInput(paste0("Job", nr), "Job")
        )
      })
    ) 
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but I am afraid that I oversimplified my issue when attempting to make sample code, and I apologize for that.  The field that I am trying to base the number of selections off of is a selectInput field, not a numericInput, and the fields that appear are outputs, rather than inputs so I am having the same issue of referring to the fields to populate the outputs in a repetitive way.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504592/for-loop-shiny-variable-assignment-2